# Pass a value to another component using Services when a change in value (dropdown selection) happens in the parent component - Angular

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-services

I'm trying to pass a value (`year_value`) from a parent component to a child component using services, whenever there is a change in the value (dropdown selection).  Also I'm using Angular routing (`<router-outlet>`) for navigation to child component, since I will be adding more charts later which are separate components.

**app.component.html**

```
<mat-toolbar class="toolbar2">
        <div>
            <button mat-button (click)="getChartType('bar')" [routerLink]="'/bar-chart'" matTooltip="Bar Chart">
                <img src="assets/images/column.svg">
            </button>
        </div>
        <div>
          <mat-form-field>
            <mat-label>Select year</mat-label>
            <mat-select placeholder="{{initialValue}}" (selectionChange)="selectByYear($event)"
                [(ngModel)]="year_value">
                <mat-option *ngFor="let year of years" [value]="year.value">
                    {{year.viewValue}}
                </mat-option>
            </mat-select>
          </mat-form-field>
        </div>
    </mat-toolbar>

    <mat-divider></mat-divider>

    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="col1"></div>
        <div class="col2">
          <div class="col2-row1 charts-area">
            <router-outlet>
              <div class="card" id="container"></div>
            </router-outlet>
          </div>
          <div class="col2-row2"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

`<mat-select>` is the dropdown and when selecting a value, the `selectByYear` updates the `year` property.

**app.component.ts**

```
  export class AppComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(private commonActions: CommonActionsService) {}

  beData = this.commonActions.getData();

  canvas: any;
  ctx: any;
  header: any;
  xValues: string[] = [];
  dataValues: any[] = [];
  yValues: number[] = [];
  year: string = '';
  initialValue: any;
  year_value;
  years: any[] = [];
  bgColors: string[] = [];
  buttons = ['Status', 'Auditor', 'ISOScheme'];
  numbers = ['Audits'];
  chart_yfield: string[] = [];
  chart_xfield: string[] = [];
  chartType;
  activity: any;
  xData: any;
  label: any;
  options: any;
  currentYear: any;

  ngOnInit() {
    this.selectYear();
    this.year_value = 2022;
    this.chart_xfield.push('Status');
    this.chart_yfield.push('Audits');
    const index: number = this.buttons.indexOf('Status');
    if (index !== -1) {
      this.buttons.splice(index, 1);
    }
    this.numbers = []
    this.header = this.chart_xfield[0]
    this.getChartType('bar');
  }

  selectYear() {
    this.currentYear = 2022;
    let earliestYear = this.currentYear - 5;
    while (this.currentYear >= earliestYear) {
      let dateOption = {
        "viewValue": this.currentYear + ' ' + '-' + ' ' + (this.currentYear + 1),
        "value": this.currentYear
      };
      this.years.push(dateOption);
      this.currentYear -= 1;
    }
    this.initialValue = this.years[0].viewValue;
    this.selectByYear(this.years[0]);
  }

  selectByYear(event) {
    this.year = event.value;
    this.getChartType(this.chartType);

    this.commonActions.setYearValue(this.year);
  }

  getChartType(type: string) {
    if (this.chart_yfield.length != 0 && this.header != '') {
      if (!this.year) {
        return;
      }
      this.chartType = type;
      this.isHighChart = true;
      this.dataValues = [];
      this.xValues = [];
      this.yValues = [];
      this.lineData = [];
      this.beData[this.year][this.header].forEach((entry) => {
        this.dataValues.push([entry.name, entry.value]);
      });
      this.beData[this.year][this.header].forEach((entry) => {
        this.xValues.push(entry.name);
      });
      this.beData[this.year][this.header].forEach((entry) => {
        this.yValues.push(entry.value);
      });
      this.beData[this.year][this.header].forEach((entry) => {
        this.bgColors.push(entry.color);
      });
      console.log(this.xValues, this.yValues, this.header, this.year);

    }
  }

}
```

So inside the `selectByYear()` I'm setting the `year`. After the value of `year` gets updated I'm updating the same in the CommonActionsService also.

**common-actions.service.ts**

```
export class CommonActionsService {

  year_value: string;

  constructor() { }

  setYearValue(year: string) {
    this.year_value = year;
  }

  getYearValue() {
    return this.year_value;
  }

}
```

Now in the bar-chart component, I call the get method. But nothing is displaying in the console.

**bar-chart.component.ts**

```
export class BarChartComponent implements OnInit {

  year_value: string;

  constructor(private commonActions: CommonActionsService) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.year_value = this.commonActions.getYearValue();
    console.log("Year Value from Bar Chart: ", this.year_value);
  }

}
```

I want to get the value of `this.year` inside the `selectByYear()` in `app.component.ts`, inside `bar-chart.component.ts` whenever the `year` updates.

Or is there any other way other than using services?

I'm adding my full code here - https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-k2touo?file=src%2Fmain.ts , but I'm not able to compile it online.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using services is the right way to share information accross component if they're not parent-child.

Here it is a matter of concurrency: you are calling `getYearValue` before it has been setted in the other component (both event are being called `OnInit`, and maybe one component is being initialized before the other).

My suggestion is to use `Subject` and `Observable`in order to create streams so that they'll always be up to date.

Here there is a [simple example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ry6myn?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.module.ts) of how you could structure it (I couldn't directly use your code since it was not compiling)

Comment: Hi @IgorCantele, I've tried your code. For the first time when the application loads, it prints "I'm loaded before" and the value of year_value is undefined. But when I change the dropdown, its not triggering again. I have updated my above description with the code I used. In the online compiler I'm also not able to run it. But you can check with the code.

Comment: Hi @IgorCantele, I got the issue. Small change in the `ngOnInit()` in product-list.component.ts of your code made it work. Need to subscribe the `yearValue$` property itself, instead of `getYearValue()`. Now the values are changing. Thanks for your code.